# Android Studio 3.6.1 won't recognize newly created resources

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated to Android Studio 3.6.1 (from 3.5.x) recently. Ever since then, when I create a new xml layout resource, Android Studio won't autocomplete the name, and it will appear like a compilation error, even though the app builds just fine. This persists until you restart Android Studio.

[image]

The app will still build and run just fine, but even after building and running it still shows as a compilation error, I cannot CMD+Click in to the file, and still can't autocomplete the name of the file.

Things I've tried:

> ```
> Clean (doesn't work)
> Rebuild (doesn't work)
> Make Project (doesn't work)
> Make Module (doesn't work)
>
> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart (WORKS!)
> ```

Obviously I can't restart Android Studio every time I add a new layout resource file. Does anyone know why this is happening, or a way I can fix it?